# Is there a name for a pure-data Objective-C class?

Tags: objective-c, data-structures, nomenclature

This is less of a code-specific question and more of an Objective-C nomenclature question.  In C you have **struct** for pure data.  In Enterprise Java, you have "bean" classes that are purely member variables with getters and setters, but no business logic.  In Adobe FLEX, you have "Value Objects".

In Objective-C, is there a proper name for an object (descended from NSObject, of course) that simply has ivars and getters/setters (or @property/@synthesize, if you want to get fancy) and no real business logic?

A more concrete example might be a simple class with getters and setters for filename, file size, description, and assorted other metadata.  You could then take a bunch of these and easily throw them into a container (NSDictionary, NSArray) without the need for messy NSValue wrapping of a C struct.  It is also a little more structure than putting, say, a bunch of loosely-typed child NSDictionaries into a parent container object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no special name (at least as far as I know).  All Objective-C objects that inherit from `NSObject` are first class objects.  You can of course implement classes with just getters and setters, but even synthesized properties have mild "business logic" for atomicity and memory management.  You can use C structs for pure data if you want (an example in Cocoa is `NSRect`), but then, as you say, it's more difficult to use with other classes such as `NSDictionary`.

Comment: I see your point about the underlying "business logic" you get with NSObject.  Arguably, you get similar baggage in Java by inheriting from java.lang.Object and yet they're still considered purely data, despite having threading-related methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official name for such a class in Objective-C. People tend to refer to such things as "value objects" or "pure data objects," but both of these are kind of overloaded since they could also be taken to refer to NSValue (or alternatively, a property list value) and NSData subclasses. The latter is the most concise way of describing them, I think.